# Get country based on GSM/UMTS network

Tags: android

I need to detect the MCC of the country in which the GSM/UMTS wireless modem is currently now.

Comment: Your question title is probably wrong, you need based on the GSM network and not WIFI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Based on GSM networks

   You need to use `getSimCountryIso()` and `getNetworkCountryIso()` from the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

   Returns the ISO country code equivalent for the SIM provider's country code.
2. Based on WIFI you use a Ip to Country database
3. You have also the option to use the [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class based on the location

Comment: None of this answer is for the "GSM/UMTS network" as asked. 1: sim, 2: wifi, 3: location.

Answer (score 0):

First get the MCC/MNC:

```
TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String networkOperator = tel.getNetworkOperator();

if (networkOperator != null) {
    int mcc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(0, 3));
    int mnc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(3));
}
```

Then, based on that, you can get the number corresponding to the selected MCC. There are plenty of lists on the internet, for example [this one on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code)